# Dell Precision 5820 USB-C Ubuntu 18.04 can't install blank screen

Tags: boot, 18.04, nvidia, dell

We 're trying to install ubuntu 18.04 on Dell Precsion 5820 USB-C type model after the install splash screen it goes to blank screen . we added below directives

In the grub "Install Ubuntu" prompt.

( Press 'e' ) Remove "quiet splash"

Add "nomodeset acpi=off"

Then hit "Ctrl + x "

Still no luck. Please let me know how to proceed from here. We already tried keeping acpi / nomodeset alone. Still no luck

Ubuntu 20.04 LTS no issues, it loaded smoothly.

In our environment, we having old versions of 5820 which worked before acpi/nomodeset

Comment: Please check if the 18.04 kernel actually supports your graphics card. Make sure to use the latest ISO which may have a newer kernel with support for that graphics card.

Comment: Already tried with the Ubuntu 18.04.5 ISO . By the way for Ubuntu 20.04 LTS there is no issue. Only this USB-C type 5820 we encountered the issue on Ubuntu 18.04